# What is the difference between tJava and tJavaRow in Talend?

Tags: java, etl, talend

What is the difference between these two talend components, as both are used to make use of Java code during transformation phase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tJavaRow must be inside a flow and will affect each row of a flow going throught.

The tJava can't be part of a flow : it must be connected to other components with triggers : "OnComponentOK" / "OnSubjobOK" / "If" or with an "Iterate".
You can use it to initialize context variables for instance.

The tJavaFlex is a mix of both : it can be part of a flow but also disconnected from it.
Its use is a bit more complex, so I would advise not using it until you are more familiar with tJava and tJavaRow.

Answer (score 1):

A blunt answer, post having hands-on experience on self question

- ***tJavaRow*** : Iterates through inputs received. Apply Java code for every iterated input.
- ***tJava*** : No iterations involved. Place it where you need to put some JAVA code. General work performed in this is like putting some value in GlobalMap, etc